# Switch странно проводит выбор после введения целочисленного значения

Tags: c, switch, break

Выполняю задачу 4.28 по учебнику Дейтела. Задача кажется простой, но при написании кода терминал выдаёт беспорядочную последовательность оператора. Если ввести '100', то сначала будет выбран первый случай, а затем default. Не сработал оператор break, затем почему-то возвращается первый случай, пропускается оператор ввода значения, и так далее. В общем, оператор работает не так, как надо. Учусь самостоятельно, ютуб, гугл, учебники не дали ответа. Задачу не перепрыгиваю, нужно в азах понять принцип оператора switch. Пожалуйста, помогите понять, думаю, логическую ошибку. Спасибо.

[image: Задача]

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    float sum = 0, salary = 0;
    int grade = 0, additional = 0;
    
    printf("Please, enter the number 1-4 of workers type to calculate sum of salaries:\n");
    while ( (grade = getchar ()) != EOF) {
        switch (grade) {
            case '1': 
                printf("Please, enter salary amount of worker:\n");
                scanf("%f", &salary);
                printf("The salary amount for worker is %f\n", salary);
                sum+=salary;
                printf("Here is clear\n");
                break;
            case '2': 
                printf("Please, enter salary amount of worker:\n");
                scanf("%f", &salary);
                printf("Please, enter amount of overhours of worker:\n");
                scanf("%d", &additional);
                salary += (salary * (salary/40) * additional); 
                printf("The salary amount for worker is %f\n", salary);
                sum+=salary;
                break; 
            case '3': 
                printf("Please, enter costs of sold goods:\n");
                scanf("%d", &additional);
                salary = 250 + (float) (additional/100) * 5.7;
                printf("The salary amount for worker is %f\n", salary);
                sum+=salary;
                break;
           case '4': 
                printf("Please, enter price for 1 produced part by worker:\n");
                scanf("%f", &salary);
                printf("Please, enter amount of produced parts by worker:\n");
                scanf("%d", &additional);
                salary = (float) salary * additional;
                printf("The salary amount for worker is %f\n", salary);
                sum+=salary;
                break;
            default : 
                printf("You wrote incorrect number of worker type. Enter again.\n");
                break;
        }
    }
    printf("The final amount of money to pay: %f", sum);        
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Добро пожаловать на Ru StackOverflow.

Вы используете функцию `getchar()`, которая считывает **один** символ с потока ввода. Скорее всего, вы запускаете программу в консоли и взаимодействуете с ней через нее - то есть вводите числа, потом нажимаете `Enter`. В таком случае у вас в буфере ввода оказывается символ `\n` (в случае *NIX-систем) или `\n\r` (в случае Windows). Он влияет на `scanf()` в `switch`.

К вашему вопросу - в случае, когда вы вводите число 100 в буфере обмена оказывается последовательность символов `100\n`, которую `getchar()` обрабатывает посимвольно, после чего все остальное предоставляется `scanf()`. То есть, как будет работать программа на таком вводе: `getchar()` считывает первый символ, это 1. Переходит в ветку, отвечающую этому выбору. В этот момент в буфере остались `00\n`. В ветке `scanf()` забирает из буфера все числа - то есть последовательность `00`, в буфере остается `\n`, который, после завершения ветки, и получает `getchar()`, после чего идет переход в ветку `default` и мы получаем сообщение о некорректном вводе варианта.

Если вы хотите делать через строки (хотя, по-моему, в данном случае проще будет действовать через ввод числа и его проверку), то можно попробовать переписать ваш код через `fgets()`/`scanf()` с модификатором `%c`

Comment: Спасибо большое за разъяснение, это мне сильно помогло. Это объяснило мне логику действия оператора куда лучше, чем краткие статьи или краткие видео объяснения.